# Neo4J - Run dbinfo command from REST API

Tags: neo4j

I want to run the

```
dbinfo -g "High Availability"
```

command over the Neo4J API. Does such an endpoint exist?

Comment: And there is also an endpoint to run shell commands: https://gist.github.com/jexp/a9bf4cd3a16eb6c5997b

Comment: Fantastic, the /db/manage/server/console endpoint is exactly what I asked for originally. Do you know where  the documentation is for this endpoint? I'm wondering what other "engine" types there are.

Comment: It's internal, so not publicly documented :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The neo4j doesn't provide endpoint for dbinfo -g.

for High Availability (HA), Its provides three REST endpoint

```
 /db/manage/server/ha/master
 /db/manage/server/ha/slave
 /db/manage/server/ha/available
```

To check more on this read their official [docs on HA](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha.html).

Comment: Thanks, 

/db/manage/server/ha 

is the one I'm looking for. Basically, I needed to see if the cluster has any master. This one does it in a simple way.